# dataframe value_counts() Shape Error

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, shapes

I am attempting to go through a time-series dataset and count the number of times each unique category of clothing appears for each day. Every year of my dataset works fine besides 2012. When I run my code I receive a shape broadcasting error and I cannot figure out why 2012 is causing this error but none of my other years are.

`test=orders['Category']['2012']
counts = test.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).value_counts()`

Here is the error the code produces

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-bc2dbf569e47> in <module>()
      1 test=orders['Category']['2012']
----> 2 counts = test.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).value_counts()

c:\users\matthew mclaughlin\miniconda3\envs\cseclass\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py in value_counts(self, normalize, sort, ascending, bins, dropna)
   3015 
   3016         # multi-index components
-> 3017         labels = list(map(rep, self.grouper.recons_labels)) + [lab[inc]]
   3018         levels = [ping.group_index for ping in self.grouper.groupings] + [lev]
   3019         names = self.grouper.names + [self.name]

c:\users\matthew mclaughlin\miniconda3\envs\cseclass\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in repeat(a, repeats, axis)
    394     except AttributeError:
    395         return _wrapit(a, 'repeat', repeats, axis)
--> 396     return repeat(repeats, axis)
    397 
    398 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (366,) (363,)
```

A sample output from my data looks similar to this

```
Order Date
2013-01-01              Outerwear
2013-01-01            Accessories
2013-01-01       First Layer Tops
2013-01-01       First Layer Tops
2013-01-01            Accessories
2013-01-01    First Layer Bottoms
2013-01-01             Kid's Sets
2013-01-01              Outerwear
```

2013-01-01              Outerwear

And what the code is suppose to produce after it runs looks like this.

```
Order Date  Category           
2013-01-01  Outerwear              289
            First Layer Tops       230
            Accessories            190
            First Layer Bottoms    155
            Footwear                10
            Kid's Sets               3
```

Ultimately, I unstack this result and insert it into new columns for each category.

Comment: `test=orders['Category']['2012']` will get you a single row. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @ cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ might be trying to get the categories for the year 2012

Comment: Yeah, orders['Category']['2012'] gets me all of the Category rows for 2012. I'm indexed on time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groupby object has no attribute called `.value_counts()`. If you want to value counts use `apply` + `stack` i.e

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).apply(lambda x : x.Category.value_counts()).stack()
```

Output for your test_data with additional dates.

```
Order Date  Category           
2013-01-01  Outerwear              3
            First Layer Tops       2
            Accessories            2
            Kid's Sets             1
            First Layer Bottoms    1
2013-01-02  Outerwear              3
            First Layer Tops       2
            Accessories            2
            Kid's Sets             1
            First Layer Bottoms    1
dtype: int64
```

If you trying to select categories based on the year then try boolean indexing like `df[df.index.year == 2012]`

Comment: groupby objects do still work with .value_counts(), just to clarify, for every other year. I get the stacked data for every day in that year. It is just 2012 that does not do so. However, your suggestion did work. Still not sure why but thank you. I am guessing it has to do with the apply function.

Comment: Hmm, Well I'll play around with my original code another time. Also a quick note, I had to remove your .stack() as the code was already stacked with value_counts(). I applied .unstack() to integrate in my other dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])   
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)    
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D'),'Category']).size()
```

If you want to test this for a specific year, here is how you select rows where the year is what you are looking for:

```
test = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2013]
test.set_index('Date',inplace=True)    
test.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D'),'Category']).size()
```

You can also use a pivot table:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Date','Category'], aggfunc=np.size)
```

Comment: You sure this will give the expected output? `Order Date` is one column name not two different ones

Comment: Hopefully, you can draw the connection between the sample column names and the column names in my examples.

Comment: What about category? Try to put the output trying your sol on sample data.